# Is the usage of "willing" grammatically wrong?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is a dialogue from Serenity (2005):

> Hoban: Yeah, but, remember the part where it's a trap?
>
> Malcolm: If that's the case, then Inara's already caught in it.
> She wouldn't set us up **willing**.

Is the usage of "willing" grammatically wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Willing** is an adjective. ("She was a willing volunteer.") In this sense it is the opposite of a word like *reluctant*.

**Willingly** is an adverb. ("She willingly volunteered to help at the party.")

In your original example, willing(ly) refers to the verb **set up**, therefore it needs to be an adverb:

> She wouldn't set us up **willingly**.

But there is another factor in play here. My memory of the *Serenity* movie is that the script is deliberately written in a cowboy style to match the space western setting of the film. I suspect that this is an intentional example of that style choice. Therefore we would need to interpret particular words and sentences in that light.

Comment: I didn't know **cowboy** grammar exist.

Comment: A good script writer will always write script to match the character of the cast. There are many examples. Imagine an English tourist in Italy, talking to someone who is not good at English. The script would need to show that tension. Or you would expect a student to use different words from her parents.

Comment: I suspect cowboy grammar is probably derived more from 1950s cowboy movies than by studying actual cowboys. That doesn't necessarily make it a poor copy, but it may have been further accentuated by such as John Wayne et al & the tradition continued. "Ah'm a-gonna git me a hoss & rustle up some cow-pokes. Darn tootin'"...